# Initial Value Problem using Finite Element

Tags: finite-element, time-integration

I am trying to implement a FEM solver for the following initial value problem
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \nabla^2 u &= f\quad \text{ in } \Omega\times (0,T)\\
u &= g\quad \text{ on }\partial\Omega\times(0,T)\\
u(x,y,0) &= u_0(x,y)
\end{align}
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is just a rectangular domain. The functions $f$ and $g$ can vary with time. I have discretized this IVP into
$$\mathbf{B}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{l} $$
where
\begin{align}
\text{B}_{ij} &= \int_\Omega \phi_i\phi_j\\
\text{A}_{ij} &= \int_\Omega \nabla\phi_i\nabla\phi_j\\
l_i &= \int_\Omega \phi_i f
\end{align}
and I can assemble these matrices and vector. I have also discretized time to get the time-stepping scheme
$$(\mathbf{B}+k\theta\mathbf{A})\mathbf{u}^{n+1} = (\mathbf{B}-k(1-\theta)\mathbf{A})\mathbf{u}^n + k(\theta \mathbf{l}^n + (1-\theta)\mathbf{l}^{n+1}), $$
where $\theta\in[0,1]$ and $k$ is the time-step.

Here comes my problem. How exactly do I impose the boundary and initial condition, implementation-wise? What changes should I make to the matrices $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$, etc? Should I do anything at each time-step? I feel like it shouldn't be too hard, however when the time is introduced it suddenly confuses me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are several equivalent ways of implementing Dirichlet boundary conditions with the finite element method. I'll give a brief overview, but you'll probably need more details, which can be found in the book [Understanding and Implementing the Finite Element Method](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0898716144).

It may be easier to analyze this for the Poisson problem $-\nabla^2u = f$ than for the heat equation; the techniques are the same in both cases, and if you understand them for the steady-state problem then it shouldn't be a big leap to adapt them to the time-dependent one. For the initial value, that amounts to setting $u^0_i = \mathbf{u}_0(x_i)$. You'll then use this as part of the right-hand side in the linear system you've written down when you go to solve for the next time-step $\mathbf{u}^1$. The boundary conditions on $\partial\Omega$ are trickier.

One way to implement Dirichlet boundary conditions is to alter the matrices $A$ and $B$ and the load vector in order to guarantee that the boundary conditions are satisfied exactly. Suppose that $i$ is some unknown of the linear system corresponding to a Dirichlet boundary point; the modification you have to make is to zero out row $i$ of $B$, set row $i$ of $A$ to be the corresponding row in the identity matrix and set $\mathbf{l}_i$ equal to $g(x_i)$.

To illustrate this approach, suppose you had a $3 \times 3$ chunk of the linear system that looked like this:

$\left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
                      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
                      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3\end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix} l_1 \\ l_2 \\ l_3\end{matrix}\right]$

and that $u_2$ is a degree of freedom corresponding to a boundary node. The modified system would look like this:

$\left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
                      0      & 1      & 0      \\
                      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3\end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix} l_1 \\ g_2 \\ l_3\end{matrix}\right]$

You can see how the modified system isn't symmetric anymore. Nonetheless, $u_1$ and $u_3$ are still coupled to $u_2$. The asymmetry of the system isn't usually an issue in practice provided that your initial guess for $u$ exactly satisfies the Dirichlet boundary conditions; try throwing the problem into a naive CG solver and see what happens. (Can you come up with a reason why this might be so?)

Another approach is to reduce the system size. Instead of solving for all of the coefficients $u_i$ in the expansion $\mathbf{u} = \sum_iu_i\phi_i$, you'll only solve for the coefficients corresponding to interior nodes. This means extracting sub-matrices out of $A$ and $B$ for those unknowns, and adding an extra component to the load vector $\mathbf{l}$ consisting of the effective forcing on the interior from boundary conditions. Referring back to the example matrices from before, we're left with the following reduced system for $u_1$ and $u_3$:

$\left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\
                      a_{31} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} u_1 \\ u_3\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix} l_1 - a_{12}g_2 \\ l_3 - a_{32}g_2\end{matrix}\right]$

Changing the linear system or deflating it are, from what I've observed, the most common approaches. You can also add on boundary conditions later as a constraint, or you can use penalty methods, but these are less common. Of the two, I tend to favor the first approach.

Comment: (+1) Thanks a lot for the answer. I will use the first type of approach, by altering the system. When I tried to do the changes myself, I encountered exactly the problem that the system no longer was postive definite, and I thought I did something wrong. I would love if you expanded on this.

Comment: Also, whenever I impose the BC for a certain boundary vertex, shouldn't I eliminate this unknown from the other rows of the system. Example, say $u_2$ is a boundary vertex. Something like this
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & 0 & a_{1,3}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
a_{3,1} & 0 & a_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}l_1-a_{1,2}g_2\\g_2\\l_3-a_{3,2}g_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You can eliminate $u_2$ from the system that you've written down; you're sort of half-way between altering the matrix and reducing the system. I've edited my answer; let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: I will have to read it in detail tomorrow, it is getting late where I live. I guess om just still in a slight state of confusion on which matrices/vectors we do changes in when imposing boundary conditions. If you consider the first linear system in my question, I have seen in some literature that they also in each row subtract the factor $b_{i,2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$ from the load vector, since my function $g$ depends on time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are also missing a discretized weak form for the boundary condition $u = g$, i.e.
$\mathbf{G} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{m}$, where $\mathbf{G}$ is assembled from the boundary elements (the basis function set for elements of $\partial \Omega$). I found the treatment in Volakis, *et al.*, "Finite Element Method for Electromagnetics" to be quite helpful regarding this basis set.

Anyway, if both $f$ and $g$ change in time, you need to recompute the respective right-hand sides before the time-stepping iteration.

Just a guess: what about unifying the volume balance equation and the boundary flux equation in one? As in

$\mathbf{B}_{\Omega} \, \partial_t \mathbf{u}_{\Omega} + \mathbf{A}_\Omega \mathbf{u}_\Omega  + \mathbf{G}_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{u}_{\partial \Omega} - \mathbf{l}_{\Omega} -\mathbf{m}_{\partial \Omega} = 0$,

where the $\partial \Omega$ and $\Omega$ subscripts should indicate the restrictions to the respective subdomains (the first method in Daniel's comment above)